# How to add alternate account in openID integration with my rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

openID integration with my rails website

User login with one openID provider account(eg.gmail)on my website , user again want to add alternate accounts(eg. facebook,  for the same account on my website, help me how can i do this...

Answer (score 0):

You just go through this link and you integration of openid with rails app.

[OpenId in your application](http://danwebb.net/2007/2/27/the-no-shit-guide-to-supporting-openid-in-your-applications)

[OpenID Authentication in Rails](http://www.practicalecommerce.com/blogs/post/471-OpenID-Authentication-in-Rails-Part-1-)

[Rails Cast for Openid With Authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic?view=asciicast)